# Assigning projection to a .tif file

Tags: coordinate-system

It was a .h5 file. I converted the datasets to .tif format using gdal. Now I want to assign projection to those files but the prescribed projection of EPSG:9805 is not found in gdal. I tried other projections like Mercator (variant A) and web mercator, but they dont seem to fit when I overlay a shapefile of the same area on it. Can anyone tell if I am going wrong anywhere or suggest some other alternative.

[image: here is the projection information]

[image: here is the product information]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.

Comment: EPSG database does not have coordinate system with code 9805. There does exist a method EPSG:9805 http://epsg-registry.org/export.htm?gml=urn:ogc:def:method:EPSG::9805. What does gdalinfo report about a) projection of the original .h5 and b) the converted GeoTIFF?

Comment: You have to build a custom mercator 2SP projection http://geotiff.maptools.org/proj_list/mercator_2sp.html with the parameters given in the file's metadata.

Comment: the projection/ co-ordinate system of .h5 file is blank according to the gdalinfo report. Projection information is given along with the datum and ellipsoid to be used to project it @user30184. Thank you.

Comment: I am searching for that method setmercator(). Thank you. @AndreJ.

Comment: That gdal does not find georeferencing automatically is no wonder by reading the driver page http://www.gdal.org/frmt_hdf5.html `There is no universal way of storing georeferencing in HDF files. However, some product types have mechanisms for saving georeferencing, and some of these are supported by GDAL.` The list is still short with only one line "HDF5 OMI/Aura Ozone (O3) Total Column 1-Orbit L2 Swath 13x24km (Level-2 OMTO3)".

Comment: On the command line, you can try `gdal_translate -a_srs '+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6356752.3142 +lat_ts=17.75 +lon_0=75 +x_0=0 +y_0=0' infile outfile `. Maybe you need to set the extent too. It might help if you can provide an online link to the hdf5 file.

Comment: i tried that on the command line...an error pops up ...Failed to process the SRS definition:'+proj=merc

Comment: i made a syntax error...it did process that command on the tif file but again  it does not overlap with the shapefile. But then shapefile has GCS lat lon projection while mercator is PCS. Is that the reason why they are not overlapping?

Comment: Unless you use a GIS software that can handle On-the-fly-reprojection (like QGIS), they would not fit, and you have to reproject one to the CRS of the other. If they still don't fit, you need to add `-a_ullr` to the gdal_translate command. You have upper left coordinates in meters in the metadata, but you still have to transform lower right from GCS to PCS too to fill it in the command line.

Comment: on the fly reprojection didnt work...i m trying to convert lower right coordinates to PCS..formulas are given here ..http://geotiff.maptools.org/proj_list/mercator_2sp.html     ......but i can't really figure them out. So still working on it

Comment: i converted GCS to PCS..and processed this command....gdal_translate -a_srs "+proj=merc +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 -a_ullr  '+ulx=-3234623.003937 +uly=5401854.420193 +lrx=3234604.5031525 +lry=-1058894.6538943' +a=6378137 +b=6356752.3142 +lat_ts=17.75 +lon_0=75 +x_0=0 +y_0=0" infile outfile.....there was no error shown and i got the output but again the shapefile is not overlapping...can anyone suggest how to check if its able to read the GCP information as  the gdalinfo of the previous output does not show GCP info.

Comment: i tried to convert the shapefile from GCS to PCS as that of my image...but it shows this error.....unable to open datasource +lon_0=75....and my command was....                                         
ogr2ogr -t_srs '+proj=merc +lat_ts=17.75 +lon_0=75 \ +k=0952692183 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs' \ out.shp in.shp....can anybody tell what this error means